# How to mirror an Anaconda installation on a new computer?

Tags: python, macos, installation, anaconda

*Main question:*

There is a computer which already has an Anaconda distribution installed with several packages (some installed by `pip` and others by `conda`). Suppose, I'd like to install the same list of packages on another computer. How to proceed with this?

*Background:*

I'll be upgrading my OS (Mac OS X Mavericks to El Capitan) and will be going for a fresh install option and moving only the folders in the home directory through a time machine drive. The Anaconda distribution is also installed under the home directory but I'm a little skeptical to keep all these packages on a much newer OS.

I was thinking of something like creating a text file with a list of installed packages and then passing the file through pip and then installing the packages over the internet.

There is a lot riding on this since all my research projects depend on this Anaconda distribution. My main packages are for machine learning and video analytics with OpenCV. There is no `menpo` repository support for OpenCV-Python-3.6 for Mac OSs yet so I'll have to stick to 3.5 for the time being.

Any suggestions or comments on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the main question, using `pip freeze` is the simplest solution as provided in the [PyPi docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files).

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt     # In the source computer terminal
pip install -r requirements.txt   # In the new computer terminal
```

For my case:

In my series of trial and error installation, it became clear there is no need to re-install all the packages; the time machine was more than enough. The Anaconda distribution was installed in the default location as `/Users/myaccount/anaconda`. I used the migration assistant to recover only my account folder (no apps and other stuff). This has also recovered the start-up file `.profile` in which the anaconda path was configured. So now, all my Python projects work without a glitch.